# React Native display images as a list from Firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a hard time understanding how to display data and images from Firebase. I have data stored in Firebase > Database > users .. the columns I am interested in users are FirstName and Email to display in a listview.
Also how to display images from Firebase > Storage.

Here is the code. Right now a blank white screen is displayed. What I am trying to do is:

1. Display users(FirstName, Email) from Firebase > Database > users and
2. extend the same to display images uploaded by the users in  Firebase > Storage.

To give an idea, I am showing here JSON export of users. Appreciate any help. Thanks !

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
      AppRegistry,
     StyleSheet,
     Text,
     TextInput,
     View,
     Image,
     TouchableHighlight,
     Button,
     ListView,
     ToolbarAndroid
  } from 'react-native';
 import * as firebase from 'firebase';
 import ListItem from './ListItem.js';
 const FbApp = require('./FbApp.js');   // firebase constants

 export default class DisplayFirebaseImages extends Component {

  constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.tasksRef = firebase.database().ref();
        const dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({
                                               rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
                                               });
        this.state = {
        dataSource: dataSource
        };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.listenForTasks(this.tasksRef);
}

render() {

    return (
            <View>
                <ListView>
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                enableEmptySections={true}
                renderRow={this._renderItem.bind(this)}
                </ListView>
                </View>
                );
         }

      _renderItem(task) {
      return (
            <ListItem task={task} onTaskCompletion={onTaskCompletion} />
              );
   }

   // start listen
listenForTasks(tasksRef) {
    tasksRef.on('value', (dataSnapshot) => {
                var tasks = [];
                dataSnapshot.forEach((child) => {
                                     tasks.push({
                                                name: child.val().name,
                                                _key: child.key
                                                });
                                     });

                this.setState({
                              dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(tasks)
                              });
                });
}
// end listen    
}


  AppRegistry.registerComponent('DisplayFirebaseImages', () =>     DisplayFirebaseImages);


ListItem.js
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
 import {
     View,Text,Image
        } from 'react-native';
    import styles from './styles.js';

    class ListItem extends Component {
     render() {
   return (
         <View style={styles.listItem}>
         <Text style={styles.listItemTitle}>
           {this.props.FirstName}
          </Text>
         </View>
    );
  }
 }

module.exports = ListItem;

  Users:
   {
     "users" : {
        "Xdsjkwjy!122" : {
            "Email" : "myemail@hotmail.com",
            "FirstName" : "Jack",
            "LastName" : "Smith",
            "MobileNumber" : "",
            "NickName" : "Jack",
            "profile_picture" : ""
        }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Don't describe your code and data structure. Instead the [minimal code and JSON that are needed to reproduce where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To have the best chance of receiving help, post the JSON as text (no screenshot). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Edited to add code and JSON export of users.